# Synthesize property errors when compiling iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I am following the tutotial on Apple's website for building your first iPhone application, as this is a field i would like to be involved in.

I completed the app, but then decided to merge it with another app. (One simply changes an image when tapped, one displays text from a text box when a button is tapped, so not too tricky to combine)

I have copied most of the code over successfully, but somewhere i have gone wrong as 6 times i get the error

```
@synthesize property must be in implementation context
```

for the 6 things i am synthesizing.

I feel like i have copied everything over, and i have checked all instances of the synthesized items so they are definitely there, so i dont know why this is occurring.

When i put the lines that are causing errors in an implemeation cointext (i.e between @implemtation and @end), i get

```
no declaration of property 'X' found in the interface
```

where x is the name of the thing i am synthesizing.

How do i put it in the interface? it seemed like i had already linked all the Interface Builder components to the relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a property in your interface

```
@interface CustomAlertViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView  *alertView;
    UILabel *label;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *alertView; <--- Property
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;    <--- Property
```

Comment: Note that this answer has a potentially dangerous mistake: the `alertView` and `label` properties get auto-synthesized using the `_alertView` and `_label` instance variables (ivars). Since you are declaring the additional `alertView` and `label` ivars, you end up with two sets: the ones starting with `_` which support the properties, and the ones that have the same name as the properties themselves. To fix this just remove the segment between braces, as recent Xcode/Objective-C versions auto-synthesize the properties and don't need that you specifically declare the supporting ivar.

Answer (score 1):

*@synthesize property must be in implementation context*

implies that you're not properly placing it between @implementation and @end.  Can you post your .m file